# Baseline alignment with textarea on Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox, textarea

I came across this weird behaviour on Firefox (96.0). I tried to align items to baseline. One of the items is textarea. What happens is, items are being align to bottom of container. I noticed that when i resize the textarea it come backs to proper alignment. On Chrome and Edge it works as expected from the beginning. Is there any known reason and solution for this behavior on Firefox?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>Before</span>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <span>After</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like a bug. However, I don't see any difference in Chrome and Edge when you *remove* `align-items: baseline`. And then it works as you want in FF, as well.

Comment: The desired result is unclear.

Comment: As far as I know, HTML and CSS don't define where the baseline of a textarea is. So neither Chromium not Gecko behaviour is more correct than the other. They're just different.

Comment: What i want to achieve is baseline alignment just like in chrome but in all browsers (firefox, chrome, edge). @MichaelBenjamin there is a difference, without setting align-items, elements got align to top of container, which looks and works different than baseline.